# Need help to start task tracker in Hadoop-1.0.4 having IO Exception.

Tags: hadoop

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-SYSTEM\mapred\local\taskTracker to 0755
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3742)
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG
```

Comment: In which operating system? What's your core-default.xml configuration? It seems the user running hadoop has not permission over the folders used by the TaskTracker

Comment: my OS is Windows XP Professional, and there is no core-default.xml i have core-site.xml it is as follows

Comment: <configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Yes, i'm using CYGWIN  @Jackopo

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of the directories, you have used as the values in your config files, to 755